# Arangodb AQL Joining, merging, embedding nested three collections or more

Tags: arangodb

I have the following collections, based on the example Arangodb doc [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-join.html) but have added a third collection called region

```
Users
{ 
  "name" : { 
    "first" : "John", 
    "last" : "Doe" 
  }, 
  "city" : "cities/2241300989", 
  "_id" : "users/2290649597", 
  "_rev" : "2290649597", 
  "_key" : "2290649597" 
}

Cities
{ 
  "population" : 1000, 
  "name" : "Metropolis", 
  "region" : "regions/2282300990", 
  "_id" : "cities/2241300989", 
  "_rev" : "2241300989", 
  "_key" : "2241300989" 
}


Regions
{  
  "name" : "SomeRegion1", 
  "_id" : "regions/2282300990", 
  "_rev" : "2282300990", 
  "_key" : "2282300990" 
}
```

I want to have a **target** result like this

```
[ 
  { 
    "user" : { 
      "name" : { 
        "first" : "John", 
        "last" : "Doe" 
      }, 
      "_id" : "users/2290649597", 
      "_rev" : "2290649597", 
      "_key" : "2290649597" 
    }, 
    "city" : { 
      "population" : 1000, 
      "name" : "Metropolis",
      "_id" : "cities/2241300989", 
      "_rev" : "2241300989", 
      "_key" : "2241300989",
      "region" : {
          "name" : "SomeRegion1", 
          "_id" : "regions/2282300990", 
          "_rev" : "2282300990", 
          "_key" : "2282300990" 
      }
    } 
  } 
]
```

The example in the Arangodb doc [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-join.html) only has queries for two collections

```
FOR u IN users 
    FOR c IN cities 
        FILTER u.city == c._id  RETURN merge(u, {city: c})

# However I want to have more than two collections e.g.
FOR u IN users 
  FOR c IN cities 
    For r IN regions
      FILTER u.city == c._id and c.region == r._id RETURN merge(????????)
```

How would you get the result with three collections joined as above? What happens if I want a forth nested one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store a document `_id` that references another collection, then you can leverage the `DOCUMENT` AQL command.

So your AQL query becomes a bit simpler, like this:

```
FOR u IN users
  LET city = DOCUMENT(u.city)
  LET city_with_region = MERGE(city, { region: DOCUMENT(city.region})
  RETURN MERGE(u, { city: city_with_region})
```

This query could be collapsed even more, but I left it like this so it's more self documenting.

What is cool about `DOCUMENT` is you can return only a single attribute of a document, such as `LET region_name = DOCUMENT(city.region).name`.

I've also found that in most cases it's more performant that doing a subquery to locate the document.

Comment: Note that the original query does _not_ use subqueries, but _nested FORs_ which are similar to a JOIN in SQL. If possible this is the preferred solution, because it usually performs better than subqueries or DOCUMENT function calls. Also, since the introduction of spliced-subqueries, the subquery performance is much better. You should also note that in a cluster a DOCUMENT call that takes an id cannot be pushed to the DB server, but must be executed on the coordinator.

Comment: By the way, you can also return only a single attribute when using nested queries or subqueries. Depending on indexes that might be used, the field in question could potentially be taken from the index, so it might not be necessary to load the full document. However, fetching a document via a DOCUMENT call _always_ loads the whole document.

Comment: It really depends on your full use case, when it's developed beyond the initial question posted here. Always do performance testing and focus on CPU/RAM/HDD usage, query performance, single/cluster performance, index optimization, data storage restructuring, and varied collection formats from many small documents, to many large documents. Everyone's mileage will vary, test and test some more.

Comment: I agree that you should always do your own performance tests. That said, nested FORs provide the best basis for the query optimizer and therefor should almost always perform best.

Comment: I have some large queries I work with, 200+ lines of AQL, and interestingly for me, the DOCUMENT command was notably faster, especially in deeply nested loops. I've also tried using Dictionary style object generation in a query to make dictionary lookups but amazingly the DOCUMENT command was faster than a dictionary or nested FOR. Testing shows amazing things.

Comment: That is rather surprising! Would you mind sharing your query and perhaps a sample data set, so I can investigate this (I am a member of the ArangoDB dev team)?

Comment: I can't sorry, the code is part of a product I develop, but the use case was resolving the username of an account when from 1 to 1500 users were returned. `username: DOCUMENT(d.user_id).username` was notably faster for us than `username: FIRST(FOR u IN users FILTER u._id == d.user_id RETURN u.username)` by a long shot. This is running on a single node.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
FOR u IN users 
  FOR c IN cities 
    For r IN regions
      FILTER u.city == c._id AND c.region == r._id
      RETURN { user: u, city: MERGE(c, {region: r } }
```

Is there a particular reason why you store ids instead of keys to refer to cities and regions? The `_id` is just a virtual field that consists of the `_key` prefixed by the collection name (plus a slash). So this would work just as well (I intentionally omit the internal _id and _rev fields):

```
Users
{ 
  "name" : { 
    "first" : "John", 
    "last" : "Doe" 
  }, 
  "city" : "2241300989", 
  "_key" : "2290649597"
}

Cities
{ 
  "population" : 1000, 
  "name" : "Metropolis", 
  "region" : "2282300990",
  "_key" : "2241300989" 
}


Regions
{  
  "name" : "SomeRegion1",
  "_key" : "2282300990"
}

FOR u IN users 
  FOR c IN cities 
    For r IN regions
      FILTER u.city == c._key AND c.region == r._key
      RETURN { user: u, city: MERGE(c, {region: r } }
```

Comment: Thanks for that but the target return does not match what I was looking for.

Comment: Why does it not match? How is it different from your expected result?